# How to change return type to map or object?

Tags: java, angular, return-value

My goal is to call a value from an API to be displayed in the UI.

This is the `ActionController` in the app that i'm calling the API from. I just added the `responseMap.put(PLAN_RESET_DATE, DateUtil.getPlanResetDate(customerRecurringChargesVO));`

```
@PostMapping("/chargeSubscriberWallet")
    public ResponseEntity<String> chargeSubscriberWallet(
            @RequestBody ChargeSubscriberWalletRequestDTO chargeSubscriberWalletRequestDTO) {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            CustomerRecurringChargesVO customerRecurringChargesVO =
                    actionService.chargeSubscriberWalletV2(
                            chargeSubscriberWalletRequestDTO.getMsisdn(),
                            chargeSubscriberWalletRequestDTO.isLocked(),
                            false,
                            null
                    );
            responseMap.put(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, PaymentUtil.convertCentToDollar(customerRecurringChargesVO.getTransactionAmount()));
            responseMap.put(CRC_UUID, customerRecurringChargesVO.getUuid());
            responseMap.put(PLAN_RESET_DATE, DateUtil.getPlanResetDate(customerRecurringChargesVO));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("chargeSubscriberWallet hits exception, {}", ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Gson().toJson(responseMap));
    }
```

And the `chargeSubscriberWalletV2` is calling this one in `ActionService`:

```
Map<String, Object> checkRenewalEligibilityV2(final String msisdn, final Long crcUuid, final boolean onlyBarredRecord)
            throws TpgException;
    CustomerRecurringChargesVO chargeSubscriberWalletV2(
            final String msisdn, final boolean isLocked, final boolean onlyBarredRecords, Long crcUuid)
            throws TpgException;
```

Meanwhile this is the client file in my app, where I call the API above:

```
@FeignClient(name = "novusSgBillClient", url = "${novus.sg.bill.url}")
public interface NovusSgBillClient {

    @PostMapping("/rest/chargeSubscriberWallet")
    ChargeSubscriberResponse chargeSubscriberWallet(@RequestBody ChargeSubscriberWalletRequest chargeSubscriberWalletRequest);
```

I just added a new value in the `ChargeSubscriberResponse` which is `planResetDate`

```
@Data
public class ChargeSubscriberResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723504501494808452L;
    private BigDecimal transactionAmount;
    private String crcUuid;
    private String planResetDate;
}
```

And the `chargeSubscriberWallet` is calling this particular function here:

```
private BigDecimal renewPostpaidPlan(ChargeSubscriberWalletRequest chargeSubscriberWalletRequest, long subscriberOrderId) throws RenewalException, JsonProcessingException {
        ChargeSubscriberResponse chargeSubscriberResponse = novusSgBillClient.chargeSubscriberWallet(chargeSubscriberWalletRequest);
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(chargeSubscriberResponse)) {
            throw new RenewalException("Renew client empty response body");
        }
        log.info("Response body from novusSgBillClient.chargeSubscriberWallet: {}", chargeSubscriberResponse);
        OrderDetail orderDetail = orderMgmtService.getOrderDetail(subscriberOrderId);
        orderDetail.setDescription(String.format("Renewed CRC with UUID: %s", chargeSubscriberResponse.getCrcUuid()));
        orderMgmtService.updateOrderDetail(subscriberOrderId, orderDetail);
        return chargeSubscriberResponse.getTransactionAmount();
    }
```

So how do I modify this function in order for it to call the `planResetDate`? I believe I have to change the return type to map or object?

Comment: You got semothing wrong there, `renewPostpaidPlan` is calling `chargeSubscriberWallet` and vice versa? This could bring you right to recursion-hell...

Comment: I just edit my question to show the `ActionController` file in details. Could you take a look?

Comment: And where is the call of `renewPostpaidPlan` ? in `actionService.chargeSubscriberWalletV2` ?

Comment: Updated the question. The first 2 coding files that I included is just for reference which is from the client app. I just need to call the API from that app to implement the `planResetDate` only. For now, it is just calling the `transactionAmount` as in the last file.